# Convert Excel value to words (in English)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

I found this formula to convert amounts into words, but it does not work 100%. Whenever an amount ends with 20,30, 40 etc it gives an error. For example 1020 will give an error but 1019 and 1021 will work fine. I have tried to fix this myself but no luck. It has to be formula (the software (Google Docs) it interfaces with cannot handle VBA scripting.

Here is the  formula :

```
=IF(H53<10^12,
    IF(INT(H53/10^9)>0,
        IF(INT(H53/10^11)>0,
            INDEX(
                {"One ","Two ","Three","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine "},
                MATCH(INT(H53/10^11),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )&"Hundred ",
        "")&
        IF(MOD(INT(H53/10^9),100)<20,
            INDEX(
                {"","One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine ","Ten ",
                "Eleven ","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen ","Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen ","Nineteen"},
                MATCH(MOD(INT(H53/10^9),100),{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19})
            ),
            INDEX(
                {"","Twenty ","Thirty ","Fourty ","Fifty ","Sixty ","Seventy ","Eighty ","Ninety "}, 
                MATCH(INT(MOD(INT(H53/10^9),100)/10),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )&
            INDEX(
                {"One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine "}, 
                MATCH(MOD(INT(H53/10^9),10),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )
        )&" Billion  ",
        ""
    )&
    IF(MOD(INT(H53/10^6),10^3)>0,
        IF(INT(MOD(INT(H53/10^6),10^3)/100)>0,
            INDEX(
                {"One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine "},
                MATCH(INT(MOD(INT(H53/10^6),10^3)/100),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )&"Hundred ",
        "")&
        IF(MOD(INT(H53/10^6),100)<20,
            INDEX(
                {"","One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine ","Ten ",
                "Eleven ","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen ","Fifteen ","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen ","Nineteen"},
                MATCH(MOD(INT(H53/10^6),100),{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19})
            ),
            INDEX(
                {"","Twenty ","Thirty ","Fourty ","Fifty ","Sixty ","Seventy ","Eighty ","Ninety "},
                MATCH(INT(MOD(INT(H53/10^6),100)/10),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )&
            INDEX(
                {"One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine "}, 
                MATCH(MOD(INT(H53/10^6),10),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )
        )&" Million  ",
        ""
    )&
    IF(MOD(INT(H53/10^3),10^3)>0,
        IF(INT(MOD(INT(H53/10^3),10^3)/100)>0,
            INDEX(
                {"One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine "},
                MATCH(INT(MOD(INT(H53/10^3),10^3)/100),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )&"Hundred ",
        "")&
        IF(MOD(INT(H53/10^3),100)<20,
            INDEX(
                {"","One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine ","Ten ",
                "Eleven ","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen ","Fifteen ","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen ","Nineteen"},
                MATCH(MOD(INT(H53/10^3),100),{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19})
            ),
            INDEX(
                {"","Twenty ","Thirty ","Fourty ","Fifty ","Sixty ","Seventy ","Eighty ","Ninety "},
                MATCH(INT(MOD(INT(H53/10^3),100)/10),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )&
            INDEX(
                {"One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine "},
                MATCH(MOD(INT(H53/10^3),10),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )
        )&" Thousand  ",
        ""
    )&
    IF(MOD(MOD(H53,10^4),10^3)>0,
        IF(INT(MOD(MOD(H53,10^4),10^3)/100)>0,
            INDEX(
                {"One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine "},
                MATCH(INT(MOD(MOD(H53,10^4),10^3)/100),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )&"Hundred ",
            ""
        )&
        IF(MOD(MOD(MOD(H53,10^4),10^3),100)<20,
            INDEX(
                {"","One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine ","Ten ",
                "Eleven ","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen ","Fifteen ","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen ","Nineteen"},
                MATCH(MOD(MOD(MOD(H53,10^4),10^3),100),{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19})
            ),
            INDEX(
                {"","Twenty ","Thirty ","Fourty ","Fifty ","Sixty ","Seventy ","Eighty ","Ninety "},
                MATCH(INT(MOD(MOD(MOD(H53,10^4),10^3),100)/10),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )&
            INDEX(
                {"One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine "},
                MATCH(MOD(MOD(MOD(H53,10^4),10^3),10),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
            )
        ),
        ""
    ),
    ""
) & " Rands"
```

Comment: What a formula! It already took me minutes to simply format it (see the edit). Take a look at the "Evalutate Formula" function - it'll walk you through each step and help you spot the mistake!

Comment: To be honest, I dont understand that formula at all. I have realized that google script can implement javascripting and there are a lot of functions in javascript that does the same thing. I'll use one of the javascript functions and not break my mind on the above formula. Thx for your suggestion though.

Comment: the formula is fixed, see the answer below - so no need for javascript...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the last part:

```
 INDEX({"One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine "},
     MATCH(MOD(MOD(MOD(H53,10^4),10^3),10),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
```

`MOD(MOD(MOD(H53,10^4),10^3),10)` will return `0`, which is not found in 1-9.

Therefore, the above line should be modified to:

```
 INDEX({"", "One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ","Seven ","Eight ","Nine "},
     MATCH(MOD(MOD(MOD(H53,10^4),10^3),10),{0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
```

This problem also exists in other areas of the formula.

All is fixed in this full formula (it also adds a few spaces that were inconsistently left out):

```
=IF(B1<10^12,
 IF(INT(B1/10^9)>0,
  IF(INT(B1/10^11)>0,
   INDEX(
    {"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine "},
    MATCH(INT(B1/10^11),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )&"Hundred ",
  "")&
  IF(MOD(INT(B1/10^9),100)<20,
   INDEX(
    {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine ";"Ten ";"Eleven ";"Twelve ";"Thirteen ";"Fourteen ";"Fifteen ";"Sixteen ";"Seventeen ";"Eighteen ";"Nineteen "},
    MATCH(MOD(INT(B1/10^9),100),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19})
   ),
   INDEX(
    {"";"Twenty ";"Thirty ";"Fourty ";"Fifty ";"Sixty ";"Seventy ";"Eighty ";"Ninety "},
    MATCH(INT(MOD(INT(B1/10^9),100)/10),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )&
   INDEX(
    {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine "},
    MATCH(MOD(INT(B1/10^9),10),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )
  )&" Billion  ",
  ""
 )&
 IF(MOD(INT(B1/10^6),10^3)>0,
  IF(INT(MOD(INT(B1/10^6),10^3)/100)>0,
   INDEX(
    {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine "},
    MATCH(INT(MOD(INT(B1/10^6),10^3)/100),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )&"Hundred ",
  "")&
  IF(MOD(INT(B1/10^6),100)<20,
   INDEX(
   {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine ";"Ten ";"Eleven ";"Twelve ";"Thirteen ";"Fourteen ";"Fifteen ";"Sixteen ";"Seventeen ";"Eighteen ";"Nineteen "},
    MATCH(MOD(INT(B1/10^6),100),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19})
   ),
   INDEX(
    {"";"Twenty ";"Thirty ";"Fourty ";"Fifty ";"Sixty ";"Seventy ";"Eighty ";"Ninety "},
    MATCH(INT(MOD(INT(B1/10^6),100)/10),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )&
   INDEX(
    {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine "},
    MATCH(MOD(INT(B1/10^6),10),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )
  )&" Million  ",
  ""
 )&
 IF(MOD(INT(B1/10^3),10^3)>0,
  IF(INT(MOD(INT(B1/10^3),10^3)/100)>0,
   INDEX(
    {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine "},
    MATCH(INT(MOD(INT(B1/10^3),10^3)/100),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )&"Hundred ",
  "")&
  IF(MOD(INT(B1/10^3),100)<20,
   INDEX(
    {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine ";"Ten ";"Eleven ";"Twelve ";"Thirteen ";"Fourteen ";"Fifteen ";"Sixteen ";"Seventeen ";"Eighteen ";"Nineteen "},
    MATCH(MOD(INT(B1/10^3),100),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19})
   ),
   INDEX(
    {"";"Twenty ";"Thirty ";"Fourty ";"Fifty ";"Sixty ";"Seventy ";"Eighty ";"Ninety "},
    MATCH(INT(MOD(INT(B1/10^3),100)/10),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )&
   INDEX(
    {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine "},
    MATCH(MOD(INT(B1/10^3),10),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )
  )&" Thousand  ",
  ""
 )&
 IF(MOD(MOD(B1,10^4),10^3)>0,
  IF(INT(MOD(MOD(B1,10^4),10^3)/100)>0,
   INDEX(
    {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine "},
    MATCH(INT(MOD(MOD(B1,10^4),10^3)/100),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )&"Hundred ",
   ""
  )&
  IF(MOD(MOD(MOD(B1,10^4),10^3),100)<20,
   INDEX(
    {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine ";"Ten ";"Eleven ";"Twelve ";"Thirteen ";"Fourteen ";"Fifteen ";"Sixteen ";"Seventeen ";"Eighteen ";"Nineteen "},
    MATCH(MOD(MOD(MOD(B1,10^4),10^3),100),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19})
   ),
   INDEX(
    {"";"Twenty ";"Thirty ";"Fourty ";"Fifty ";"Sixty ";"Seventy ";"Eighty ";"Ninety "},
    MATCH(INT(MOD(MOD(MOD(B1,10^4),10^3),100)/10),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )&
   INDEX(
    {"";"One ";"Two ";"Three ";"Four ";"Five ";"Six ";"Seven ";"Eight ";"Nine "},
    MATCH(MOD(MOD(MOD(B1,10^4),10^3),10),{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
   )
  ),
  ""
 ),
 ""
) & " Rands"
```

Comment: Wow! We have already implemented the javascript but i'm sure this is going to help someone else out there. Thx very much.